# Synchronization between process context and interrupt context in Linux

Tags: networking, tcp, synchronization, virtual-machine

I met some problems when I did some research in improving the TCP/UDP performance of Virtual Machine(VM), if anybody can offer me some help or suggestion to handle my problem, I will be very appreciated.

RPS & RFS works well on physical machine, but they may not work on VM sometimes. For example, RFS aims to send IRQ to the CPU running the corresponding receiving process. However, virtual CPU (vCPU) of each VM can not be always online when several vCPUs share one physical CPU (pCPU) (Here we can simply assume the vCPU scheduling is round-robin.). Therefore, sending IRQ to an offline vCPU is not meaningful even though the target user level process is running on it. Theoretically, sending NIC IRQ to the running vCPU of VM will shrink the NIC IRQ handling latency and improve the TCP/UDP performance. So I assign a virtual co-processor (co-vCPU) which is almost always online to each VM and pin NIC IRQ of the VM to this co-vCPU. From the view of Guest OS in VM, the user process (e.g. iperf) runs on one core and the IRQ context of eth0 runs on another core. In my experiment, it works well for UDP but does not work for TCP.

I doubt that it is due to the synchronization between process context and IRQ context. Because when I read some source code of TCP layer in linux, I found that both IRQ context (e.g. tcp_v4_rcv() in net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c) and user context (e.g. tcp_recvmsg() in net/ipv4/tcp.c) call lock_sock()/unlock_sock() when they access the buffers in kernel(receive_queue, backlog_queue, prequeue). Therefore sometimes IRQ can not access the receiving buffer locked by another vCPU which runs the user level receiving process (iperf server) and this vCPU holding the lock has been descheduled by VM monitor(VMM) or hypervisor.

I am not sure I described my problem clearly. Anyway, welcome any suggestion on it.